# Concise R data.table syntax for modal value (most frequent) by group

Tags: r, data.table, frequency

What is efficient and elegant data.table syntax for finding the most common category for each id? I keep a boolean vector indicating NA positions (for other purposes)

```
dt = data.table(id=rep(1:2,7), category=c("x","y",NA))
print(dt)
```

In this toy example, ignoring NA, `x` is common category for `id==1` and `y` for `id==2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to ignore `NA`'s, you have to exclude them first with `!is.na(category)`, group by `id` and `category` (`by = .(id, category)`) and create a frequency variable with `.N`:

```
 dt[!is.na(category), .N, by = .(id, category)]
```

which gives:

```
   id category N
1:  1        x 3
2:  2        y 3
3:  2        x 2
4:  1        y 2
```

Ordering this by `id` will give you a clearer picture:

```
 dt[!is.na(category), .N, by = .(id, category)][order(id)]
```

which results in:

```
   id category N
1:  1        x 3
2:  1        y 2
3:  2        y 3
4:  2        x 2
```

---

If you just want the rows which indicate the top results:

```
dt[!is.na(category), .N, by = .(id, category)][order(id, -N), head(.SD,1), by = id]
```

or:

```
dt[!is.na(category), .N, by = .(id, category)][, .SD[which.max(N)], by = id]
```

which both give:

```
   id category N
1:  1        x 3
2:  2        y 3
```

Comment: This risks dropping groups that have only NAs, btw... maybe join them back or something in that case `dt[!is.na(category)][, .N, by=.(id, category)][order(-N)][.(unique(dt$id)), on=.(id), .SD[1L], by=id]` or just give ordering preference to non-NAs: `dt[, .N, by=.(id, category)][order(is.na(category), -N), .SD[1L], by=id]`